# check is a particular tab or subsection is present

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

Is it possible to use web crawling with scrapy and a base url to check if a website has a particular section, sub section or tab or not? For example, here

https://www.christiani.de/

on of the tabs is Service. This tab further contains sections including **Kataloge anfordern**. I want to search the whole website if there is a **Kataloge** section anywhere such that the section name can also include other words for example anforden. Can I achieve this using scrapy? The tutorials that I have seen work with css selectors but those might be different for all websites. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

So far I can see the text "**Kataloge**" is being used in `<a>` and `<span>` tags. Based on this data you can use the following `xpath` to fetch the instances of word "**Kataloge**" used and then print the text part.

```
no_of_instances=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Kataloge')] | //span[contains(text(),'Kataloge')]")
for i in no_of_instances:
      print(i.text)
```

Output must be words: Kataloge, Kataloge anfordern or Kataloge {{any_random_text}}

Comment: where do you see the text Katalog being used in the Inspect section? what div is this under? I cant seem to find it

Comment: and is there a way to navigate to that Katlog section if found? So that we can scrape something from there

Comment: I see two instances of the text "Kataloge" (check screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJkaF.png). It's either under a `<a>` or `<span>`. So if you run the above patch I suggested, you'll get the text instances where ever "Kataloge" is used. Then you can simply search the text in your site by `ctrl+f` and `ctrl+v`